# BayesTraits Error: Does have a translate line

Tags: error-handling, terminal, evolutionary-algorithm

I am running a test on behavioral evolution, using the multistate function of BayesTraits v. 4.0.0. I have my rooted treefile Tree.trees (using FigTree), my list of specimens in a .txt like like below:

```
Sp_1 AC
Sp_2 E
Sp_3 ABD
...
and so on
*There are over 300 specimens included in my phylogeny, 
and some have multiple behavioral patterns recorded for a single species, 
relating to the multi-lettered samples such as Sp_3 doing three behaviors (ABD). All are tab deliminated.
```

and an Input.text as

```
1
2
Run
```

My files look the exact same as the example files, but when I try to run this in command line on a Mac OS,

```
./BayesTraitsV4 Pomp.trees Pomp.txt < PompIn.txt
```

I get

```
Err: Does have a translate line
```

I have not found any information about this error, what it means, or how to fix it. I hope someone could give some guidance, thank you!

Comment: I have found the source of the error. While my Nexus treefile has a transfer 'line', BayesTraits needs a transfer 'block' instead, so that meant I had to go in to the treefile, open it in TextEdit (on a mac), and manually create the transfer block and change all the names in the phylogeny to the numbers representing each specimen. Then, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's right. Trees in nexus format without a translate table will produce that error. Instead of editing the tree file manually, I have found that importing the trees in R with ape::read.nexus() and then exporting the trees with phytools::writeNexus() will get your tree(s) in the right format.